# Classifying image using image segmentation in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, image-segmentation

I am trying to classify a Landsat 8 image in google earth engine. I have to classify them object based, since I am building on an earlier research where they have used object based classification.

Create objects has been done in the same way as in the segmentation session of the user summit https://code.earthengine.google.com/189e4388e81f01c967b72c0bd78d5d45. I also took ndvi and evi in to account.

I have ended with a bunch of objects, which I made into vectors. Is there a way that I can assign these polygons to a class?

Can I code which particular polygon would represent a particular class, so that my generated objects will become my training areas?